# Select where tuple in statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with two FK `UserProfile_Id` and `Service_Id`. This table contains bit field which value I need to change.

I have two temporary tables:

First table **#temp2**:

```
EmailAddress,
UserProfile_Id
```

Second table **#temp**:

```
EmailAddress,
Service_Id
```

This statement does not work:

```
UPDATE MailSubscription SET BitField=1
where UserProfile_id IN ( SELECT UserProfile_Id from #temp2 ) 
      and Service_id IN ( SELECT ServiceId from #temp)
```

I know why it does not work, but have no idea how to fix it to work fine.

I need to change `bitField` for `MailSubscription` where **tuple**(UserProfile_Id,Service_Id) is in joined #temp and #temp2, but I can not write it like this in mssql.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Do you have error or it doesn't update expected rows?

Comment: @Parado It does not update valid rows because I need to search by 2 columns at one time not separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE M
SET M.BitField=1
from MailSubscription M
inner join #temp2 t2 on M.UserProfile_id=t2.UserProfile_Id
inner join #temp t on M.Service_id=t.ServiceId
and t.EmailAddress=t2.EmailAddress
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE MailSubscription SET BitField=1
FROM #temp2
JOIN #temp on #temp2.EmailAddress=#temp.EmailAddress
WHERE MailSubscription.Service_id = #temp.ServiceId 
  AND MailSubscription.UserProfile_id =  #temp2.UserProfile_Id
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know you could omit the updated table from the `from` clause and still refer to it, but it actually works

Answer (score 2):

You could use a filtering join:

```
update  m
set     BitField = 1
from    MailSubscription m
join    #temp t1
on      t1.Service_id = m.Service_id
join    #temp2 t2
on      t2.UserProfile_Id= m.UserProfile_Id
        and t1.EmailAddress = t2.EmailAddress
```

Comment: @Parado: You're right, `#temp2` should've been linked on `UserProfile_id`, updated in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with EXISTS operator

```
UPDATE MailSubscription
SET BitField = 1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 
              FROM #temp2 t2 JOIN #temp t ON t2.EmailAddress = t.EmailAddress
              WHERE t2.UserProfile_Id = MailSubscription.UserProfile_Id
                AND t.Service_Id = MailSubscription.Service_Id
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help u find the answer.

```
Update 'Tablename'
SET Mailsubscription = 1
WHERE concat(UserProfile_Id ,".", Service_Id) IN ( 
                        SELECT concat(t.UserProfile_Id , "." , t2,Service_Id)
                        FROM #temp t INNER JOIN #temp2 t2 
                               ON t2.EmailAddress = t.EmailAddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update MailSubscription set
    BitField = 1
from MailSubscription as MS
where
    exists
    (
        select *
        from #temp2 as T2
            inner join #temp as T on T.EmailAddress = T2.EmailAddress
        where
            T2.UserProfile_Id = MS.UserProfile_Id and
            T.Service_Id = MS.Service_Id
    )
```